# Proof a language is not regular using Pumping Lemma

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

I am trying to prove that the following language is not regular using the pumping lemma.

> L = {a<sup>k</sup> b<sup>3l</sup> a<sup>l</sup> | k ≥ 1 , l ≥ 0}

I have decided to choose w = a b<sup>3p</sup> a<sup>p</sup>, then |w| = 4p+1 ≥ p

Any tips?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the exact formulation of the pumping lemma that you are using. At any rate, this is a rather tricky case, because standard formulations like in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) only let you pump somewhere in a prefix of fixed length. But your initial block of a allows pumping anywhere and can be arbitrarily long. Thus you have to use some additional property. I suggest two:

- Regular languages are closed under reversal. Thus you may as well look at $L^R = {a^l b^{3l} a^k}$. Now any pumping in the initial block of a will lead out of the language.
- Regular languages are closed under intersection. If you take the intersection with a b+ a+ you end up with ${a b^{3l} a^k}$, and now pumping in the b block will take you out of the language.

Comment: I changed the string w according to your suggestion. Then I can take x=empty string, y = a, and z the rest and it's done.